# Is there a "Bipartite" Szemeredi-Trotter theorem?

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, incidence-geometry

One version of the Szemeredi-Trotter theorem states the following:

Given a set of $L$ lines in the plane, the number of points incident to at least $k$ lines is bounded above by a constant times $L/k + L^2/k^3$.

This version of the theorem can be found here in notes written by Adam Hesterberg for Larry Guth's polynomial method class: http://math.mit.edu/~lguth/PolyMethod/lect6.pdf.

Let's suppose instead that I have a collection of $R$ red lines and $B$ blue lines, where $R$ is much smaller than $B$ (like $R$ is about $B^{1/2}$ or so).  Assume that none of the red lines are parallel.  I would like a bound for the number of points lying on at least one red line that are incident to at least $k$ blue lines.  It's possible to use the Szemeredi-Trotter theorem to get a bound of $B/k + B^2/k^3$ by just ignoring the condition that the points need to lie along a red line.  Does anyone know if a better bound is possible?

Comment: When $k >> L^{1/2}$ this version of the Szemeredi-Trotter theorem tells us that the best you can do, up to a constant factor, is partition the lines into $L/k$ sets of size $k$ and have all the lines each part coincide at a point.  Seems to me that if we are in this range we could just put all these intersection points on a single red line,  so in this range $B/k$ should still be optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will describe a construction in the dual setting.

Take a $(k+1)\times n/k$ size grid of points.
Color the top row red, the rest blue, so we have $n$ red points and $k$ blue points.
The number of lines that contain one point of each row is $\Theta(n^2/k^3)$.

So translating it back to your problem, this gives a construction of $B^2/k^3$ if $R=k$, so this shows that your bound is sharp if $R\ge k$.

Comment: Thanks!  Between this and Nate's comment, I think that completely answers my question.